which one is correct for the complex integration $C_k=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{\sin \left(\zeta-\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)}{\zeta^{k+1}} d \zeta $
when I calculate the complex integral$$
C_k=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{\sin \left(\zeta-\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)}{\zeta^{k+1}} d \zeta
$$
where $C:z=e^{i t}, $ $t: 0 \rightarrow 2 \pi$
$$
$$I got two different answsers.
My solution is:
(a)$$
\begin{aligned}
& C_k=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin \left(e^{i t}-e^{-i t}\right)}{e^{i t(k+1)}} e^{i t} i d t . \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin (2 i \sin t)}{e^{k i t}} \cdot i d t \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin (2 i \sin t) e^{-k i t} d t \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi}-i \sinh (2 \sin t) e^{-k i t } d t \\
& \begin{array}{l}
\\
=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi-i \sinh (2 \sin (t+\pi)) e^{-k i(t+\pi)} d t
\end{array} \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi i \sinh (2 \sin t)(\cos k t-i \sin k t)(-1)^k d t \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sinh (2 \sin t) \cdot \sin k t \cdot(-1)^k d t \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
but the other solution is:
Take $z=e^{i \theta}$ so that $d z=i e^{i \theta} d \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
c_n & =\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin (2 i \sin \theta) i e^{i \theta}}{e^{i(n+1) \theta}} d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi i \sinh (2 \sin \theta)(\cos n \theta-i \sin n \theta) d \theta .
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that $\sinh (2 \sin \theta)$ is an odd function in $\theta$, hence
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sinh (2 \sin \theta) \cos n \theta d \theta=0 .
$$
Finally,
$$
c_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sinh (2 \sin \theta) \sin n \theta d \theta, \quad n=0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \cdots .
$$
$\textbf{My problem}:$the second answer dont have the term $(-1)^{k}$,but my solution has.if the two solution both is correct,does it mean $c_{k}=0\quad $if k is odd number?

If I were you, I would write $\sin(\zeta-\frac{1}{\zeta}) = \sin\zeta\cos\frac{1}{\zeta} - \cos\zeta\sin\frac{1}{\zeta}$ and determine the residue through the Laurent series of the integrand instead.
